# How to return Form from onClick listener?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the react-app with onClick Button. The simply version of one of it’s components looks like this:

```
export const Filters= props=>{
return(
          </div>
           <button 
           onClick={AddReview()}>
            Add review
          </button>
    </div>
    )
  }
```

And the component with event hendler is here:

```
export default function AddReview() {
        return (
         <div className="filter" style={{ margin: "300 px"}}>
              <h2>Board</h2>
              <Form>
             <FormGroup>
            <Label for="player">Player</Label>
            <Input name="player" placeholder="Ex: Player 1"></Input>
          </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </div> 
        );
      }
```

So my task is to return Form from the event handler onClick, but I faced with the warning:

"Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got a value of object type"

How can I avoid this problem? Thank you!

Comment: You are calling the function in your `onClick` listener (`AddReview()`). This means that the returned value of that function will be put between the curly braces `{ }`. Remove the parenthesis `()` from the function reference.

Comment: But besides that, what do you expect to happen whenever `AddReview` is called? It's a component, not a function you should run. And what does *return Form from the event handler onClick* mean?

Comment: Your `Filters` component has a button that calls `AddReview` and `AddReview` component has a div with class `filter`... that's pretty confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event handler is a `void` function that cannot return anything.  You want to add a `state` to your component that tells you whether or not to show the `AddReview` component.

```
const [isAddingReview, setIsAddingReview] = useState(false);
```

In your event handler, you update this state.

```
onClick={() => setIsAddingReview(true)}
```

Then you conditionally render the `AddReview` component only when `isAddingReview` is `true`.

Here I am showing an "Add Review" `button` when it's `false` and the `AddReview` component when it's `true`.  Likely there are callback functions that you want to pass to `AddReview` as props.  For example, we can pass a function to close the form which you might call inside `AddReview` when the form is submitted.

```
export const Filters = () => {
  const [isAddingReview, setIsAddingReview] = useState(false);

  return(
    <div>
      {isAddingReview
      ? // when true
      <AddReview
        close={() => setIsAddingReview(false)}
      />
      : // when false
      <button 
        onClick={() => setIsAddingReview(true)}
      >
         Add review
      </button>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!